# Windows 7 like taskbar for Linux

Tags: linux

Is there a standalone taskbar/panel replacement for Linux that behaves like the Windows 7 taskbar, with pinning and big square icons and no text?

The current Ubuntu panel covers most of it but it stays on the left instead of the bottom (and AFAIK that's not customizable). More importantly, I think it's tied to Ubuntu and it can't be used as a drop-in replacement in other distro's or Desktop Environment such as LXDE, KDE, etc.

I'm on LXDE, which is a fairly lightweight DE, and most of its components aim to be DE-independent.

Comment: You could change lxpanel's settings, but I don't know if that'd be enough Windows 7-like…

Comment: @wb9688 I've tried that, but it doesn't cover pinning. Plus the icons look weird (like they are cropped), but mostly there is no pinning.

Comment: You can have a `launchbar` in lxpanel, but it acts more like Windows XP, btw the icons don't look weird on my machine when I make the panel bigger…

Comment: Ubuntu form `16.04` above supports moving the dock to the bottom.

Comment: @enedil I'll try it but I doubt it can be used standalone in another DE.

Comment: I use an xfce panel at the bottom of the screen with the following applets: Show Desktop, Window Buttons (a task bar with a nice grouping option - e.g. group by app names.  optional text, icons, or both.  the size of the icons depends on the size of the panel), Workspace Switcher, Notification Area (a systray), and Audio Mixer.  Works well for me.  I also have a panel at the top of the screen with main menu, launcher icons for commonly used apps, various status displays, and Date/Time.